# Editing index.js Cloud Functions file in Flutter project

Tags: node.js, android-studio

I'm finally starting with `Cloud Functions` for my Flutter app but I'm very new to javascript, `NodeJs` and the whole procedure. I use Android Studio and I have installed NodeJs and locally the modules I need (mainly `Stripe` and `http`), but when I write code in the `index.js` I don't see any suggestion(apart for variables I declared) or text color for the code as it is for any `.dart` file, so I'm never able to see if I'm writing correct code or not. Is there something else I have to set up?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the `Node.js` plugin by IntelliJ is only available for their Ultimate, their expensive enterprise version, not very clever choice in my opinion..,.. so goodbye IntelliJ ... welcome VisualStudio.. what a bummer dough..